# I want to remove header with numbers in dataframe can anyone tell?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
     0   1        2       3       4        5
0   CIK CONAME  FYRMO   FDATE   FORM    SECFNAME
1    xc  rg      tg      dxv     frv      rfrv
```

1>Here i want to remove indexing of column names and make the characters(CIK, CONAME,.....) as column names, And also i want to index the rows.

```
**Expected Output**:
  
    CIK CONAME  FYRMO   FDATE   FORM    SECFNAME
1    xc  rg      tg      dxv     frv      rfrv
2     x   x       x       x       x         x
```

Comment: How did you get your dataframe?

Comment: the header got in the initial dataframe i got hoang when i read the csv file @QuangHoang

Comment: a method would be to do `df.columns = df.iloc[1]; df = df.iloc[1:]` simplier still would be to pass in the `skiprows` arg to your dataframe creation statement. i.e `pd.read_csv(...,skiprows=1)`

Comment: So i wanted to remove the header and assign row indexing

Comment: okay @Umar.H . thank you but it is deleting the column names in dataframe but not deleting the numbers which is header

Comment: @SaiNikhilKataru `df.index + 1`?

Comment: @Umar.H not working indexing and as well as removing header

Comment: @Umar.H it worked for this  df.columns = df.iloc[0] indexing at 0 but still row indexing not changed